# How to download CSR ADK 4.1 and CSR ADK 3.0?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, csr

goep.h, goep_apphdrs.h, oppc.h, opps.h, ftpc.h, ftps.h
CSR ADK 3.0 says that these files exist in CSR ADK 4.0. How can I use these files?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using xIDE for MainADK4.1, I will highlight the steps to include the libs mentioned by you:

1. Open xIDE and Open your recent Workspace you are working on.
2. Then from the title bar select **Project** drop-down menu.
3. Select **Properties**
4. Double click on **Configuration Properties** folder in left task pane.
5. Double click on **Build System** folder, you will see tabs like '*Property*' and '*Value*' in the right pane.
6. Scroll down to **Libraries** and include (by typing) the required ***.h** files (without the extension **.h*).
7. Click on *OK* and then **Build Active Project** (from *Build Menu*).

NOTE : if you are changing the source code of Libraries itself then you have to build the libraries first using the *VM libraries* executable present when you install the Main ADK.

Hope this helps you.